# Capitalising a list - Stuck on capitalising the First Item of the list

Tags: haskell

Using the function capitalise write a function which, given a list of words, capitalises them as a title should be capitalised. The proper capitalisation of a title is as follows: The first word should be capitalised. Any other word should be capitalised if it is at least four letters long. For example,
title ["tHe", "sOunD", "ANd", "thE", "FuRY"]
==  ["The", "Sound", "and", "the", "Fury"]

I am stuck on capitalising the first word of the list.

```
-- capitalise

-- List
capitalise :: String -> String
capitalise (head:tail) = Char.toUpper head : map Char.toLower tail
capitalise [] = []

-- title

lowercase :: String -> String
lowercase xs = [ toLower x | x <- xs ]

-- List 
title :: [String] -> [String]
title xs = [ if length x < 4 then lowercase x else capitalise x | x <- xs ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just follow the same pattern you did in `capitalise`: treat the first item specially, and then map a non-discriminating function over the rest of the list.